# How to create a EF code first database on different location other than LocalDb

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, connection-string

I am developing MVC 5 application with MSSQL Server 2014, which is using 2 databases. One using Database first approach and one using code first approach(default database for users registration and roles in MVC 5).

When I deployed the application on our production server which is providing SQL server 2008, the code first database gives the following error on User Registeration.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot get a local application data path. Most probably a user profile
>   is not loaded. If LocalDB is executed under IIS, make sure that
>   profile loading is enabled for the current user. )

So, I thought that since production server is using SQL Server 2008, so may be it won't be able to create a LocalDb, so I changed the connection string for my code first database as follows;

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="PUConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=**my server name**;AttachDbFilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\aspnet-web erp-20150603105840.mdf&quot;;Initial Catalog=&quot;aspnet-web erp-20150603105840&quot;;UID=**my user name**;PWD=**password**;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and my **identitymodels.cs** code is:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("name=PUConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Then it gives the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

at the following line of **register method** in **AccountController**

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

So, kindly guide me how to create this code first database on my production server if it is providing SQL 2008.

Comment: Create an empty database in the server, set the `initial catalog` of the connection string to the created database name, and remove `attachdbfilename` from connection string.

Comment: Thanks, It worked... Moreover I have to delete "UserInstance=true" statement..